# UrhoSharp (3D for Xamarin) crashes in the Sample constructor

Tags: xamarin

From what I googled, I could not find solution.
UrhoSharp GIT, is solution built with VS2015.
I created new Xamarin mobile platform solution.
Copied the relevant files over from sample UrhoSharp project.
Then ran the Windows(UWP) propject. it crashes.

(I did it this way as there were too many issues with building the sample project that was created in VS2015)

```
 protected Sample(ApplicationOptions options) : base(options) { }



      Throws an exception.
      System.Exception
      HResult=0x80131500
        Message=Implementation assembly (iOS, Android or Desktop) is not           referenced
        Source=UrhoSharp
         at Urho.UrhoPlatformInitializer.DefaultInit()
```

Comment: `...Implementation assembly (iOS, Android or Desktop) is not...` You have not added  the Urho package to your UWP application project (it will provide the native implementations for Windows/UWP)

Comment: It is added, I will double check... here is project : https://app.box.com/s/odlj7mwjldo59bkmrwzi4ap2wc9xy8hn

Comment: It is added       https://ibb.co/wp1G91n

Answer (score 1):

Try to update to latest UrhoSharp package (1.9.67 at this moment), clean and rebuild the whole solution. It helped in my case.